# What are all the Christmas decorations you can place?

Tags: merry-clickmas

After you get the Reindeer Stables, you can add decorations through a text form to increase production speed. I've added a few decorations myself, but I was wondering what all of them are. I know that some entries seem to be "synonyms". For example, if you enter "wreath" and then "garland", you'll only add the "a Christmas wreath" and trying to put up the garland will return "We already have a Christmas wreath".

These are the decorations I've already added along with discovered synonyms.

- Nutcracker (Nutcracker)
- a Christmas tree (tree)
- baubles (bauble)
- glass ornaments (ornament)
- a star (star)
- Christmas lights (lights)
- a Christmas wreath (wreath, garland)
- mistletoe (mistletoe)
- a Christmas stocking (stocking)
- candy canes (candy cane)
- a chimney decoration (chimney, fireplace)
- a Santa decoration (santa)
- an elf decoration (elf)
- a reindeer decoration (reindeer)
- a nativity scene (stable)
- toys (toy)
- wrapping paper (wrap)
- candles (candles)
- tinsel (tinsel)
- a star (star)
- an angle (angle)
- holly (holly)
- paper chains (chains)
- Christmas crackers (cracker)
- Christmas cards (card)
- a figure of Mary (mary)
- a figure of Joseph (joseph)
- a figure of Jesus (jesus)
- wise men figures (wise men)
- a donkey decoration (donkey)
- a sleigh decoration (sleigh)
- a snowman (snowman)
- snow decoration (snow)
- Santa hats (hat)
- bells (bell)
- ribbons (ribbon)
- a turkey decoration (turkey) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the source code you can use the following, the first part is the full name and the second are the things you can enter to get the decoration.

To get a partridge for example you can enter "partridge" or "pear tree" but you'll only get 1 "A partridge in a pear tree".

If you want to save yourself some typing and cheat your way to instant speed you can use the following by copy pasting it in the URL bar and pressing enter:
`javascript:for(d in decorations ) decorations[d].have = true; update_reindeer();`
This will instantly unlock all the decorations.

- A Christmas tree, "tree"
- A partridge in a pear tree, "partridge", "pear tree"
- Tinsel, "tinsel"
- Baubles, "bauble", "ball"
- Glass ornaments, "ornament", "glass decoration"
- A star, "star"
- An angel, "angel"
- A fairy, "fairy", "faerie", "faery"
- A cherub, "cherub"
- Pine cones, "pine cone", "pinecone", "fir cone"
- christmas lights, "light"
- Candles, "candle", "tealight"
- A lantern, "lantern", "lamp ", "lamps "
- Bells, "bell ", "bells "
- Five gold rings, "ring"
- A trumpet, "trumpet", "horn", "cornet"
- A drum, "drum"
- Ribbons, "ribbon", "bow", "tape"
- Glitter, "glitter"
- A Merry Christmas banner, "banner", "merry christmas", "happy christmas", "merry xmas", "happy xmas"
- A Christmas wreath, "wreath", "garland"
- Mistletoe, "mistletoe"
- Holly, "holly"
- An advent calendar, "advent", "calendar"
- Paper chains, "chain"
- christmas crackers, "cracker"
- christmas cards, "card"
- christmas presents, "present", "parcel", "box", "gift", "prezzie", "prezzy"
- Toys, "toy"
- Wrapping paper, "wrap", "gift-wrap"
- A Christmas stocking, "stocking"
- A Christmas sack, "sack"
- Candy canes, "candy", "candie", "sweets"
- Chocolate decorations, "chocolate"
- A Christingle, "christingle", "orange"
- A nativity scene, "nativity", "bethlehem", "stable", "manger"
- A figure of Mary, "mary"
- A figure of Joseph, "joseph", "joeseph"
- A figure of Jesus, "jesus", "christ "
- Shepherd figures, "shepherd"
- Wise men figures, "wise men", "wise man", "king"
- A toy soldier, "soldier", "tin man", "tin men"
- A donkey decoration, "donkey", "ass ", "mule"
- A robin decoration, "robin"
- A reindeer decoration, "deer", "reindeer ", "rudolph"
- A penguin decoration, "penguin"
- A polar bear decoration, "polar bear"
- A santa decoration, "santa", "father christmas", "saint nic", "st nic"
- An elf decoration, "elf", "elves"
- A sleigh decoration, "sleigh", "sled ", "sleds "
- A Christmas pudding decoration, "pudding"
- A turkey decoration, "turkey"
- A chimney decoration, "chimney", "fireplace"
- A snow globe, "globe"
- A snowman, "snowman", "snow man", "snowmen", "snow men", "frosty"
- Snow decoration, "snow", "flake"
- Icicles, "icicle", "ice"
- Santa hats, "hat"
- A lump of coal, "coal"
- A nut cracker, "nut cracker"
- A toy train, "train"

Comment: YOU EVIL NINJA.

Comment: you forgot nutcracker, come on man

Comment: @trev I did not forget anything, that is the list of items in the game as it was 1 and a half years ago, when I answered this question.

Comment: As proposed by an anonymous user:  Ivy, "ivy"; Poinsettia, "poinsettia"; Chestnuts roasting on an open fire, "chestnuts". I prefer letting the original poster add these if she/he chooses to do so.