# What are all the Christmas decor items in Merry Clickmas?

Tags: merry-clickmas

Every time I search the internet for what all of the Christmas items on the list in Merry Clickmas, I only find incomplete lists.

Right now I have **360%** on my *current speed* - these are the decorations I have unlocked (each decoration adds +4% speed):

---

- a Christmas tree
- a partridge in a pear tree
- tinsel
- baubles
- glass ornaments
- a star
- an angel
- a fairy
- a cherub
- pine cones
- Christmas lights
- candles
- a lantern
- bells
- five gold rings
- a trumpet
- a drum
- ribbons
- glitter
- a Merry Christmas banner
- a Christmas wreath
- mistletoe
- holly
- an advent calendar
- paper chains
- Christmas crackers
- Christmas cards
- Christmas presents
- toys
- wrapping paper
- a Christmas stocking
- a Christmas sack
- candy canes
- chocolate decorations
- a Christingle
- a nativity scene
- a figure of Mary
- a figure of Joseph
- a figure of Jesus
- wise men figures
- a toy soldier
- a donkey decoration
- a robin decoration
- a reindeer decoration
- a penguin decoration
- a polar bear decoration
- a santa decoration
- an elf decoration
- a sleigh decoration
- a Christmas pudding decoration
- a turkey decoration
- a chimney decoration
- a snow globe
- a snowman
- snow decoration
- icicles
- santa hats
- a lump of coal
- ivy
- poinsettia
- a nutcracker
- a toy train
- a Christmas pickle
- chestnuts roasting on an open fire
- and a gingerbread house

---

Are there any more or is that the limit?

Comment: Hi Luna Cat, welcome to Arqade! I have edited your question somewhat and added the items you've already found, so that answerers can focus on any potential ones you've missed. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all the Christmas decorations you can place?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146452/what-are-all-the-christmas-decorations-you-can-place)

Answer (score -1):

These are the Decorations I know about so far. Each decoration adds +4% speed. The current maximum speed I've reached is 360%

Here are the decorations:

- a Christmas tree
- a partridge in a pear tree
- tinsel
- baubles
- glass ornaments
- a star
- an angel
- a fairy
- a cherub
- pine cones
- Christmas lights
- candles
- a lantern
- bells
- five gold rings
- a trumpet
- a drum
- ribbons
- glitter
- a Merry Christmas banner
- a Christmas wreath
- mistletoe
- holly
- an advent calendar
- paper chains
- Christmas crackers
- Christmas cards
- Christmas presents
- toys
- wrapping paper
- a Christmas stocking
- a Christmas sack
- candy canes
- chocolate decorations
- a Christingle
- a nativity scene
- a figure of Mary
- a figure of Joseph
- a figure of Jesus
- wise men figures
- a toy soldier
- a donkey decoration
- a robin decoration
- a reindeer decoration
- a penguin decoration
- a polar bear decoration
- a santa decoration
- an elf decoration
- a sleigh decoration
- a Christmas pudding decoration
- a turkey decoration
- a chimney decoration
- a snow globe
- a snowman
- snow decoration
- icicles
- santa hats
- a lump of coal
- ivy
- poinsettia
- a nutcracker
- a toy train
- a Christmas pickle
- chestnuts roasting on an open fire
- and a gingerbread house